# How to save downloaded file to internal directory in android studio?

Tags: android

I download an SQLite database from Firebase. it saves into device Storage (Android/data/package name/files/Download). **Can I save the database to the internal directory?** (like assets folder to use it). I want no person can access to this file after *decompiling* app!

```
private void downloadFileFirebase() {
    storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    ref = storageReference.child("test.sqlite");
    ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            String url = uri.toString();
            download(MainActivity.this , "test" ,".sqlite" , DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS , url );
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        }
    });
}
```

and:

```
public void download(Context context , String fileName , String fileExtension , String destinationDirectory , String url){

    DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context , destinationDirectory , fileName + fileExtension);
    downloadManager.enqueue(request);
}
```